# stack in Python

Tags: python, stack

Why in the following code on uses `return` with all methods but not with `append`?

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

Comment: Because `append`s changes the `item` in place and then return `None`, so there's no point to `return` the result of an `append` method, as the `item` would be changed regardless.

Comment: why do you expect otherwise?

Comment: Class level variables are a little less intuitive if you're not used to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'return' will return value back to the calling function.

If you want your code to tell you what's on top of the stack, the function needs to return it to the caller. Think of it like asking someone what's in the fridge, they will tell you what's in there -> that's the return value.

If you put something on a stack, you already know what it is, so no one needs to return it to the caller. If I ask someone to put my milk in the fridge, they don't need to additionally tell me it was milk

Answer (score 0):

It could have used `return`; there just wasn't any *reason* to do so.

First, remember that a function with no explicit return value implicitly returns `None`. It does not, as in some languages, return the value of the last statement
in the function.

Next, note that `self.items.append(item)` already returns `None`. So returning the return value of `append` has the exact same behavior as having no explicit return value.

Consider, by way of contrast, `isEmpty`. It would behave very differently if you had written

```
def isEmpty(self):
    self.items == []
```

Now, whether or not `self.items` was empty, `isEmpty` would always return `None`. The `return` is essential to actually *return* the Boolean result of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is for supplying information from inside the function to the caller, and it is used when the caller needs to query information from some set of objects.

Some functions do not serve the purpose of querying information, but rather as directives commanding action on an object, and since such function's purpose is not to generate information, they don't need to return anything. `push()` is an example of such a function.